# Execute Javascript from Textarea - JSHint eval is evil

Tags: javascript, jquery, eval, jshint

fiddle - http://jsbin.com/zepugadafa/edit?js,output

I recently learned of [Eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

My script works fine, but JSHint is saying `eval is evil`.

I don't want to disable the eval alert from Codemirror. Just rewrite my click function (still using eval, or some other form of eval to get it to work the exact same way).

I tried...

```
$("#download").on("click", function() {
  var call = new Function( $("#jszipdemo").val() );
  return call();
});
```

but got `The Function constructor is a form of eval.`

---

The only way I've found that works without any errors is appending the script to the body, but still haven't figured out an alternative measure, that isn't so in my opinion redundant as I like to separate my javascript code from my html.

```
var script = "<script>" + content + "</script>";
$('body').append(script);
```

Does anyone know of a workaround to get rid from this alert, while still having my function run (without disabling eval on Codemirror, and not having to append a script to the body)?

```js
var widgets = [];
var waiting;

function updateHints() {
  editor.operation(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < widgets.length; ++i)
      editor.removeLineWidget(widgets[i]);
    widgets.length = 0;

    JSHINT(editor.getValue());
    for (i = 0; i < JSHINT.errors.length; ++i) {
      var err = JSHINT.errors[i];
      if (!err) continue;
      var msg = document.createElement("div");
      var icon = msg.appendChild(document.createElement("span"));
      icon.innerHTML = "!!";
      icon.className = "lint-error-icon";
      msg.appendChild(document.createTextNode(err.reason));
      msg.className = "lint-error";
      widgets.push(editor.addLineWidget(err.line - 1, msg, {coverGutter: false, noHScroll: true}));
    }
  });
  var info = editor.getScrollInfo();
  var after = editor.charCoords({line: editor.getCursor().line + 1, ch: 0}, "local").top;
  if (info.top + info.clientHeight < after)
    editor.scrollTo(null, after - info.clientHeight + 3);
}

editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("jszipdemo"), {
  lineNumbers: true,
  mode: "javascript",
  lint: true,
  gutters: ["CodeMirror-lint-markers"]
});

editor.on("change", function() {
  clearTimeout(waiting);
  waiting = setTimeout(updateHints, 500);
});

setTimeout(updateHints, 100);
```

```css
@import url("http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/3.0.1/normalize.css");
@import url("http://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.css");
@import url("http://codemirror.net/addon/fold/foldgutter.css");
@import url("https://codemirror.net/addon/lint/lint.css");


.CodeMirror {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.lint-error {
  font-family: arial; 
  font-size: 70%; 
  background: #ffa; 
  color: #a00; 
  padding: 2px 5px 3px; 
}
.lint-error-icon {
  color: white; 
  background-color: red; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  border-radius: 50%; 
  padding: 0 3px; 
  margin-right: 7px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/javascripts/code-completion.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/javascripts/css-completion.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/javascripts/html-completion.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/xml/xml.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/css/css.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/edit/closetag.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/edit/matchbrackets.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/selection/active-line.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/keymap/extra.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/fold/foldcode.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/fold/foldgutter.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/fold/brace-fold.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/fold/xml-fold.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/fold/comment-fold.js"></script>
<script src="https://codemirror.net/addon/lint/lint.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jshint/r07/jshint.js"></script>
<script src="https://codemirror.net/addon/lint/javascript-lint.js"></script>

<script src="http://stuk.github.io/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://stuk.github.io/jszip-utils/dist/jszip-utils.js"></script>
<script src="http://stuk.github.io/jszip/vendor/FileSaver.js"></script>

<textarea id="jszipdemo" rows="4" cols="35">$("#download").on("click", function() {
  return eval( $("#jszipdemo").val() );
});</textarea>
```

Comment: The problem is that `eval` *is* evil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call JSHint with the **evil** option set to false.

```
JSHINT(editor.getValue(), {evil:false});
```

Comment: I don't want to disable the eval alert from Codemirror. Just rewrite my click function (still using eval, or some other form of eval to get it to work the exact same way).

Comment: I fear there is not other way to evaluate strings to code in javascript. And eval is evil so, it's really one or the other. :(